# javax.sql.datasource getconnection returns null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

How can I fix the code below so that it does not throw an error?

The following line of code is giving me a null pointer exception:

```
return dataSource.getConnection();
```

Note that dataSource is an instance of javax.sql.DataSource which is specified in web.xml, and which works fine when called by other code.

Here is the actual method in DataAccessObject.java where the null pointer is occurring:

```
protected static Connection getConnection(){  
  try {
     return dataSource.getConnection();  //
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

The preceding method is being called by this line of code:

```
connection = getConnection();
```

Which is located in the following method in a class called CourseSummaryDAO as follows:

```
public List<CourseSummary> findAll(Long sid) {
    LinkedList<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = new LinkedList<CourseSummary>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnection(); //
        String sql = "select * from coursetotals where spid=?";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setLong(1, sid);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        //for every row, call read method to extract column 
        //values and place them in a coursesummary instance
        while (rs.next()) {
            CourseSummary coursesummary = read("findAll", rs);
            coursesummaries.add(coursesummary);
        }
        return coursesummaries;
     }catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
     } 
     finally {
        close(rs, statement, connection);
    }
 }
```

To recreate this simply, I created the following TestCourseSummaries class:

```
public class TestCourseSummaries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long id = new Long(1002);
    CourseSummaryDAO myCSDAO = new CourseSummaryDAO();
    List<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = myCSDAO.findAll(id);
    for(int i = 0;i<coursesummaries.size();i++){
    System.out.println("type, numunits are: "+coursesummaries.get(i).getCourseType()+","+coursesummaries.get(i).getNumUnits());
    }
}
}
```

### Edit

To address JustDanyul's question, I am enclosing the code that calls in my application, and the underlying DataAccessObject code which is extended by the two DAO objects in the calling code:

Here is the code in my application which triggers the error.  See there are two classes that each extended DataAccessObject.  Perhaps they are conflicting with each other, causing the second one not to get the database connection?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {  
   String idString = req.getParameter("id");
   Long id = new Long(idString);
   ThisObj thisobj = new ThisDAO().find(id);
   req.setAttribute("thisobj", thisobj);
   ThoseObjDAO myThoseDAO = new ThoseObjDAO();
   List<ThoseObj> thoseobjects = myThoseObjDAO.findAll(id);
   req.setAttribute("thoseobjects", thoseobjects);
   jsp.forward(req, resp);
}
```

And here is the code for the DataAccessObject class which is extended by the two DAO classes in the calling code:

```
public class DataAccessObject {
private static DataSource dataSource;
private static Object idLock = new Object();

public static void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
   DataAccessObject.dataSource = dataSource;
}

protected static Connection getConnection() {
   try {return dataSource.getConnection();}
   catch (SQLException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
}

protected static void close(Statement statement, Connection connection) {
   close(null, statement, connection);
}

protected static void close(ResultSet rs, Statement statement, Connection connection) {
   try {
      if (rs != null) rs.close();
      if (statement != null) statement.close();
      if (connection != null) connection.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
}

protected static Long getUniqueId() {
   ResultSet rs = null;
   PreparedStatement statement = null;
   Connection connection = null;
   try {
      connection = getConnection();
      synchronized (idLock) {
         statement = connection.prepareStatement("select next_value from sequence");
         rs = statement.executeQuery();
         rs.first();
         long id = rs.getLong(1);
         statement.close();
         statement = connection.prepareStatement("update sequence set next_value = ?");
         statement.setLong(1, id + 1);
         statement.executeUpdate();
         statement.close();
         return new Long(id);
      }
   }
   catch (SQLException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
   finally{close(rs, statement, connection);}
}
}
```

The data source is created in web.xml, as follows:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>dataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>datasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: @BalusC I just added more code above, showing how the error is actually generated in my real code.  Can you show me how to fix the problem in my real code, show in the edit above?

Comment: @BalusC The datasource is created in web.xml.  I added the code at the end of my original posting above, just now.  Does this answer your question?  In the doGet method, everything works fine when I comment out the creation/use of the second DAO.  The problem comes when I try to create two different classes which each extend DAO in the same doGet method.  Creating and using one of those classes works fine.  Can you show how to get past this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the code where it "runs fine" in, is code actually running in an application server. The example you are posting, which just runs a `static void main()` method, wont get any resources which has been defined in web.xml.

I am guessing that you use JDNI to setup the initial datasource. And then using something like

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/mydb")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

to set up your connection. Right?

EDIT:

After seeing your code, it seems like your data source is newer initialised at all. Just putting a  element into your web.xml will not do it alone. You will also need to actually configure the dataSource, you know, specify the driver, username, password, uri etc etc etc.

I'm guessing the find() method of the DAO that works, isn't actually using the dataSource. What you have shown so far, doesn't insigunate that your have a initialised dataSource at all.

Just to give you an idea, I liked a tutorial on how you would do this with Tomcat and JDNI. (Or even better, use spring-jdbc).

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help.  I put more code above including the actual calling code (which has two instances of classes that extend DataAccessObject), and the code for the underlying DataAccessObject.  Is the problem the resource lock?  If so, how do I avoid the error in the doGet method that I added above without removing the desired protection from the resource lock?

Comment: I think your problem is that the dataSource is never initialised. I have no idea what the lock is there for? Its highly likely that your database is transactional, do a transaction, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and then commit when your are done. No need to involve intrinsic locks :D

Comment: Thank you, but can you please write out some actual working code based on your suggestions and on what I put up in my posting?  I am trying to understand, and that will be easier if you give me some working code to pick through.

Answer (score 1):

Use dataSource as `<javax.sql.DataSource>` instance, rather than an instance of `<javax.activation.DataSource>`.

In short, you should replace the statement `<import javax.activation.DataSource;>` by this other `<import javax.sql.DataSource;>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use dataSource as javax.sql.DataSource instance, rather than an instance of javax.activation.DataSource. In short, you should replace the statement:

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;
```

by this other:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```